# How to automatically create a dir in user's home when adding new user?

Tags: apache-2.2, freebsd

I am toying with Apache and FreeBSD.

I'm using UserDir in Apache, and configured it to look at the 'www' dir under each user's $HOME.

My question is: which is the best way to automatically create the 'www' dir for each user while adding them (adduser)?

Is there an option in adduser cmd that I am missing? Or maybe should/can I edit it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

there is a `-k` command line option but there is a better way to do this. Each user's home directory is initialize from `/usr/share/skel`. If you create there `www` directory then each newly created user will have it.

Comment: True! Shame on me for haven't thought it first:) Thank you!